# Subtracting 8-bit integers in Python

Tags: python, integer, bit-manipulation, 8-bit

I'm trying to use Python to calculate a checksum by repeatedly **subtracting a series of 8 bit values.** However, I don't know how to do this in Python.

---

**In context:**
I have the following C code I'm trying to convert to Python:

```c
#define uint8_t unsigned char
static uint8_t fix_header(uint8_t *header) {
    uint8_t sum = 0;
    uint8_t count = 0xbc - 0xa0;

    /* complement check of 0xa0 - 0xbc */
    header = header + 0xa0;

    while (count-- > 0) {
        sum = sum - *header++;
    }

    sum = (sum - 0x19);

    return sum;
```

It's the [checksum code for GBA game headers](http://nocash.emubase.de/gbatek.htm#gbacartridgeheader). I'm having trouble replicating this in Python. I can do everything except `sum = sum - *header++;`, since (as far as I know), Python has no limit on how large a variable can be. I've tried this using Python's `int` but this gives incorrect checksums. From what I can see the 8-bit limit is doing something special I don't understand or know about.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do 8-bit arithmetic in Python, simply do regular integer arithmetic and strip off the last 8 bits of the result.

```
count = (0xbc - 0xa0) & 0xff
```

This works for unsigned values. If you need a signed result, check to see if it's greater than 127 and subtract 256 if it is.

```
count = count - 256 if count > 127 else count
```

This whole function is rather un-Pythonic though. I'd translate it as follows:

```
def fix_header(header):
    sum = 0
    for b in header[0xa0:0xbc]:
        sum -= ord(b)
    sum = (sum - 0x19) & 0xff
    return sum
```

I make the assumption here that `header` is a bytestring and thus `ord` is necessary to turn the bytes into integers. I also think that converting the result to 8 bit can be done once at the end instead of at every calculation.